# Intercept All Relative Paths

Tags: asp.net-mvc, path

Is it possible to intercept all and any relative paths used in an application and remove/edit a portion of it before the absolute path is evaluated?

Example:

In mvc view page-

```
<%= Html.Image("~/{somefolder}/logo.png") %>
```

I want to intercept the relative path "~/{somefolder}/logo.png" and replace "{somefolder}" with a folder location retrieved through some logic (database, if/else etc.)

Comment: At what point do you want to do this interception? When displaying pages that link to those assets? Or when the requests come in to the web server?

Comment: Before the page is completely outputted to the visitor, any and all instances of "{somefolder}" in any url would be replaced by something I want. I assume this would need to be done when the relative url is resolved into an absolute one, server side, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a helper that does that.

For example...

```
public static string LinkedImage(this HtmlHelper html, string url)
{
  Regex regex = new Regex("({(.*?)})");//This is off the top of my head regex which will get strings between the curly brackets/chicken lips/whatever! :).
  var matches = regex.Matches(url);

  foreach (var match in matches)
  {
    //Go get your value from the db or elsewhere
    string newValueFromElsewhere = GetMyValue(match);
    url = url.Replace(string.Format("{{0}}", match), newValueFromElsewhere);
  }

  return html.Image(url);
}
```

In terms of looking to resolve the url itself, you might want to look [here](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/02/18/asp.net-mvc-tip-47-ndash-using-resolveurl-in-an-html.aspx) at Stephen Walther's blog.

Comment: I want to be able to replace {somefolder} in any relative "~/" path URL.

From what the article you linked, if I can somehow override the VirtualPathUtility class (assuming everything goes through that) I could easily do it. I'll look into it some more.